# Unknown number of arguments so one or more discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def hellothere(ctx, *, msg):
await ctx.send(ctx + msg)
```

It didn't work when I tried "hello hi hi hi hi"; I'm hoping for it to print back "hi hi hi hi" or if I typed five hi's it would send back 5 hi's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting an error like this:

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'commands.context.Context' and 'str'
```

Instead of adding the `Context` (`ctx`) and `msg` simply send the `msg`

```py
@bot.command()
async def hellothere(ctx, *, msg):
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Also as @yungmaz13 said, your indentation is incorrect, though I think this is just a copying mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To accept an arbitrary number of arguments, the `*` parameter must be *named*. Here, the `*` is just a syntactic marker separating the required positional argument `ctx` from the keyword-only parameter `msg`. `msg` is optional, but if present, must be a keyword argument, not a positional argument:

```
hellothere("hello")   # Good
hellothere("hello", msg="world")  # Good
hellothere("hello", "world")  # Bad
```

Comment: discord.py doesn't process them like that, the `*` is used for multi-word input, [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)